# Moving DOM elements on resize and load. Only works on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move `#project-right-content` right underneath `h1.entry-title` on both resize and load. So far, it only works on resize. Why doesn't it work on load?

```
$(window).on('resize load', function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 934) {
        $('#project-right-content').insertAfter('#project-left-content .entry-title');
    } else {
        $('#project-right-content').insertAfter('#project-left-content');
    }

});
```

Here's the HTML for what I'm trying to do:

```
<div id="project-wrapper>
    <div id="project-container">
        <div class="post-container">
            <div id="project-left-content">
                <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>  <--- after this line |
                <p>Description goes here.</p>                            |
            </div>                                                       |
            <div id="project-right-content">      <-- THIS should be moved
                <div id="slider">
                    <div id="slides">
                        <!-- Slide goes here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could just write function for load and  just invoke it inside $( document ).ready().

Comment: Have you tried to run your example isolated? Because I have and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window` object doesn't fire a `load` event.

One option would be to chain the [`.resize()` method](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) *after* the event listener in order to trigger a `resize` event when the page has loaded.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2k4zke4L/)

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 934) {
        $('#project-right-content').insertAfter('#project-left-content .entry-title');
    } else {
        $('#project-right-content').insertAfter('#project-left-content');
    }
}).resize();  // <-- added
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but there isn't any change. It still doesn't move the elements on load, only on resize.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. It was already wrapped within a DOM ready handler.

Comment: @J82 That's interesting. It works in the example I provided. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working in your case. Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah it's strange. I can see that it's working in your example. There aren't any errors in the console either.

Comment: @J82 The only other thing I can possibly think of without seeing your site would be the jQuery version. In the example I am using 1.9.1.. what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.11.1. [This is the site](http://staging.keebs.com) if it helps any. The relevant part is when you hover over one of the boxes, click on the + sign, and the project slides down from the top. Within this slide down section, if the window is less than 934, the image slide should be right underneath the title of the project.

Comment: I think it's because the HTML that is affected is part of the Ajax response. Does this mean that I have to somehow 'reactivate' it after the response comes through?

Comment: @J82 Yes, likely. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As I sad in answer try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 934) {
      $('#project-right-content').insertAfter('#project-left-content .entry-title');
    } else {
      $('#project-right-content').insertAfter('#project-left-content');
    }
  }

  resize();

  $(window).on('resize', resize);

});
```